# Error in deserializing body of request message for operation ? Try changing MaxNameTableCharCount Property

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF Service with 60 Operation Contracts.

When I try to add another Operation Contract I get the following error:

Error in deserializing body of request message for operation

**Answer:**

I changed the MaxNameTableCharCount Property of the binding configuration to **32768** (default is **16384**).

It worked for me!

Hope it helps you too!

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! Thanks a bunch for sharing. Can you edit your question, make it a "true question" and move the part with the answer to an actual SO answer? See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) for more tips on answering your own question.

Comment: Can you provide more detail into this. What binding configuration etc.?